# using the simple past in the present tense

Tags: sentence-construction

In the sentence given below

> [It is quite apparent that the Narendra Modi government **did not want** the language issue to acquire disproportionate importance at a time when it is embarking on its second innings with a huge mandate.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/crisis-defused/article27429380.ece)

The entire sentence is in the present tense but why are they using the past tense **(did not want)**

Is it a case of subjunctive mood?

Comment: Your example sentence has nothing to do with subjunctive mood. It's a compound sentence in which the tense that fits the logic of the sentence should be used.

Comment: The sentence is in the present, but the part "did not want"  occurred in the (recent) past, so it is just fine to write it in the past tense.

Answer (score 2):

Break the sentence up to see why different tenses are used.

The government IS embarking on a new term with a huge mandate.
As the government prepared to take office again, it DID NOT WANT the language issue to dominate politics.
This situation IS still apparent.

You could easily construct a much simpler model sentence using the same tenses.

If a student had declined an invitation to attend a concert, one might say:

**It seems that she DID not want to be distracted when she is writing exams.